# Pyglet update batch data

Tags: python, opengl, draw, pyglet

I am using Pyglet batches to draw hundreds of quads. I would like to update the position of the verticies and the color values of the quads while the game is running. How can I do this? I have looked through a lot of the Pyglet Documentation and the closest thing I could find is:

```
    'c4f/static'
```

versus

```
    'c4f/dynamic'
```

My batch usage looks like this:

```
    self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, self.texture, 
      ('v3f/dynamic', self.verticies), ('c4f/dynamic', ((1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0)*4))

    ...
    def on_draw(self):
      self.batch.draw()
```

Comment: You need to iterate through the vertices generated by `self.batach.add()`by placing the return object in a variable. `x = self.batch.add(...)` and then do `for index in range(len(x.vertices)): x.vertices[index] = New_Value`.

Comment: Great, that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pyglets `batch.add` returns a vertice object that you can manipulate.
Switch your code to looks like the following:

```
v = self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, self.texture, ('v3f/dynamic', self.verticies), ('c4f/dynamic', ((1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0)*4))

...
def on_draw(self):
    for index in range(len(v.vertices)):
        v.vertices[index] = v.vertices[index] +1
    self.batch.draw()
```

This is a crude example of how to manipulate it, ultimately you want to step in your `range()` call and update x,y pairs.

Comment: Is there a way to remove a quad from the batch?

Comment: @lilcutthroat You should be able to do `v.delete()` IIRC. If all else you might need to re-create the batch. But according to [the docs](https://pythonhosted.org/pyglet/api/pyglet.graphics.Batch-class.html) `Call VertexList.delete to remove a vertex list from the batch.` should be the way to go. (I usually keep all my vertices in a dictionary, as soon as I've done `batch.add` i add the returning values to say `self.objects[ID] = batch.add(...)` in order to keep a "state" and work with the objects afterwords.

Comment: @lilcutthroat You're welcome : ) Good luck with your project!