# My pyglet Batches don't have an add() attribute

Tags: python, pyglet

Almost every example I can find of adding a vertex list to Batches in pyglet involves invoking the Batch's add() method, but for some reason Batches I create don't have any such method. I am able to add shapes to batches via pyglet.shapes objects, but I want to be able to do it the other way instead.

Here's an example of something I've tried. The problem occurs at the end of this snippet, where I try to use add() right after creating a new Batch.

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import key

class Player:
    def __init__(self, pos, color):
        self.pos = pos
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 5
    
    def move(self, direction):
        if direction[0] == 0 and direction[1] == 0: return;
        self.pos = addV(self.pos, scaleV(direction, self.speed / magnitude(direction)))

class Block:
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, nomask = False):
        self.nomask = nomask
        self.w, self.h = w, h
        self.l, self.r, self.b, self.t = x, x+w, y, y+h

class MainWindow(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1/60.0)

        self.player = Player((10, 10), (255, 0, 0))
        self.blocks = [Block(50, 50, 100, 50)]

        self.blockBatch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

        for b in self.blocks:
            self.blockBatch.add(4, pyglet.gl.GL_POLYGON, None, ("v2i", (b.l,b.b,b.l,b.t,b.r,b.t,b.r,b.b)), ("c3B", (0,0,255)*4))
```

Any ideas as to why this might be happening? Is it a version issue?

Here's the error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\(me)\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\CTF\scripts\masktest.py", line 85, in <module>
    window = MainWindow()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\(me)\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python\CTF\scripts\masktest.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.blockBatch.add(4, pyglet.gl.GL_POLYGON, None, ("v2i", (b.l,b.b,b.l,b.t,b.r,b.t,b.r,b.b)), ("c3B", (0,0,255)*4))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Batch' object has no attribute 'add'
```

Comment: I think that might be from old examples for Pyglet 1.5 where [.add() used to exist](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.5-maintenance/modules/graphics/index.html?highlight=Batch#pyglet.graphics.Batch). But no longer exists in the [Batch](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/graphics/index.html#pyglet.graphics.Batch) class of Pyglet 2.X.

Comment: Ah, okay! Interesting how I couldn't find any posts about it yet. So, is the best way to do it now to just create pyglet.shapes(s) and setting their batch attribute?

Comment: It was a while since I did any kind of 3D, so I wouldn't know. But even back in Pyglet 1.5 I used to [access the vertice lists manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44098212/929999) and add objects to them there. Not sure that's advisable anymore tho.